# Can the values of this structure be accessed/modified without using a for loop?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

Here’s my initial structure array:

```
A(1).B.C = 'a';
A(2).B.C = 'b';
A(3).B.C = 'a';
A(4).B.C = 'a';
```

I want to change the values of field `C` based on values of `Values` and indexes of `IndexingArray`:

```
Values = {'a', 'b'};
IndexingArray = [1 1 0 1];
```

So, my new structure array will be:

```
A(1).B.C = 'b';
A(2).B.C = 'b';
A(3).B.C = 'a';
A(4).B.C = 'b';
```

Is there a way to do it without using a for loop?

Comment: this is not even remotely a signal processing question. I think you meant to ask this on StackOverflow, and ask your phase-related StackOverflow question here!

Comment: I can't think a way of doing this without a for loop.... Is there any reason why a for loop does not work for you? This are not matrices, thus you won't find much improvement by avoiding a for loop (if possible).

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this without loops using [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) and [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) syntax, but it might look a little harder to read:

```
% Initialize A:
A(1).B.C = 'a';
A(2).B.C = 'b';
A(3).B.C = 'a';
A(4).B.C = 'a';
Values = {'a', 'b'};
IndexingArray = [1 1 0 1];

temp = [A.B];           % Structure array containing B substructures
[temp.C] = deal(Values{IndexingArray+1});  % Set field C of each structure element
temp = num2cell(temp);  % Convert to a cell array of 1-by-1 structures
[A.B] = deal(temp{:});  % Update B substructures
```

And in newer versions of MATLAB, you can omit [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) altogether:

```
temp = [A.B];
[temp.C] = Values{IndexingArray+1};
temp = num2cell(temp);
[A.B] = temp{:};
```

This should allow you to update the `B` and `C` fields without affecting any other fields that might exist in your more complicated structure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the value, it is simpler to rebuild the structure array.

- Get value by `IndexingArray`:

  ```
  val = Values(IndexingArray+1);
  ```
- Build array of structures using `cell2struct`, and convert to cell array using `num2cell`:

  ```
  T = num2cell(cell2struct(val, {'C'}, 1));
  ```
- Convert `T` result to array of structures using `cell2struct`:

  ```
  A = cell2struct(T', {'B'}, 1);
  ```

---

Here is the code sample to create A:

```
Values = {'a', 'b'};
IndexingArray = [1 1 0 1];

val = Values(IndexingArray+1);

T = num2cell(cell2struct(val, {'C'}, 1));

A = cell2struct(T', {'B'}, 1);
```

---

Building A in a single line of code:

```
A = cell2struct((num2cell(cell2struct(Values(IndexingArray+1), {'C'}, 1)))', {'B'}, 1);
```

---

Result (for testing):

```
>> A(1).B.C

ans =

b

>> A(2).B.C

ans =

b

>> A(3).B.C

ans =

a

>> A(4).B.C

ans =

b
```

---

Solution using `arrayfun`:

```
val = Values(IndexingArray+1);

A = arrayfun(@(x) struct('B', struct('C', val{x})), 1:4)
```

---

**Update specific elements of A:**

In case you need to update specific elements, instead overwriting `A`, you can apply `arrayfun` selectively, to the indexes, you know you need to update.

Example:

Assume `A` length is 6 elements, and you need to update the first 4, you can use the following code:

```
A(1:4) = arrayfun(@(x) struct('B', struct('C', val{x})), 1:4);
```

Assume you know you need to update only `A(1)` and `A(4)`, you can use the following example:

```
A(1).B.C = 'a';
A(2).B.C = 'b';
A(3).B.C = 'a';
A(4).B.C = 'a';
A(5).B.C = 'c';
A(6).B.C = 'd';

Values = {'a', 'b'};
IndexingArray = [1 1 0 1];

val = Values(IndexingArray+1);

%List of indices of A to update
indices = [1, 4];

A(indices) = arrayfun(@(x) struct('B', struct('C', val{x})), indices);
```

Comment: I tested your last solution, but it overwrites the whole struct A.
Isn't there a way to update a specific field, rather than overwriting the struct A?

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if this is what you have meant.

Comment: If struct A has more than one field (e.g., B and D), your solution doesn't work because I only want to update field B, but it overwrites the whole. I only want to selectively update fields B and C and not any other fields that struct A or struct B possess

Comment: I think there is no way to do it without a `for` loop (there could be a way using `eval`). Do you like me do delete my answer (giving others better chance answering)?

Comment: Before I delete my answer, can you please revise your answer: Add all the additional constrains you wrote in comments to your post. Mention struct `A` has more than one field (e.g., `B` and `D`). Mention you want to update a specific field. Please give a code sample that reflects all these requirements. Consider posting a solution that uses a for loop to your question...

Comment: As far as I know `arrayfun` is a for loop, inside. I doubt this can be done without a for loop!